# Mvvmcross TableView Binding Triggers Twice

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

When creating a Android application with Mvvmcross and Monodroid I have an activity that consists of a table. When pressing an element of the table the binding of the ItemClick method is called twice. This is probablamatic as it causes issues with other elements of the view.

TableView.axml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="..."
android:id="@+id/TableView_Container"
style="@style/TableView_SearchContainer">
<Mvx.MvxListview
    android:id="@+id/TableView_List"
    style="@style/TableView_List"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource StackInfos;ItemClick OnClick;"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/list_item" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The OnClick method is called twice as tested with logging.

Is this a known Mvvmcross issue? Is there a way I can trace the binding further?

Is there a known fix?

Comment: So apparently the double trigger decided to change behavior after I loaded the project in VisualStudio then change back to Xamarin. Really not sure why it was doing that.

Answer (score 2):

> The OnClick method is called twice as tested with logging.

I just tested this on the listview from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples

I modified the viewmodel with:

```
public class ListViewModel : BaseListTestViewModel
{
    private int i = 0;

    public ICommand HelloCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => Mvx.Trace("Hello " + ++i));}
    }
}
```

and the view with:

```
  <MvxListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;ItemClick HelloCommand"
  />
```

Looking at the trace and the Android debug log, there's only one call per item click - `i` increments with once each click.

---

> Is there a way I can trace the binding further?

You could increase the binding logging verbosity using `MvxBindingTrace.TraceBindingLevel = MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic;` - but I doubt this would tell you much.

You could build the MvvmCross source yourself - or get the debug assemblies and pdb files from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Binaries/

You could copy the `MvxListView` source from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs into a new class in your application - say `MyListView` - and then use 'normal debugging techniques' on that list view in your application.